# Shell - Using string variables that contain double quotes

Tags: mysql, shell

I have a shell script that is taking in lines from a file, and sending them to a database via mysql. However, some of the lines it is reading contain double quotes.

Example - `This is a "line from a file" with words`

This line winds up getting put into a variable, to be fed into the mysql command to send it to the database. This is where the problem arises. The quotes in the variable, are causing an error in the mysql command.

Example:

```
MySQLString='INSERT INTO MyTable (`id`, `line`,) VALUES (NULL, "'"$LifeFromFile"'")'
mysql -uName -pPass --execute "$MySQLString"
```

Comment: honestly, this is the kind of situation where I use Perl instead of shell;  use a shell script to call the Perl script, but let Perl read in the contents of the file and make the MySQL calls, so that you can use parameter binding, and avoid quote-escaping madness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use `printf` here:

```
line='This is a "line from a file" with words'

printf -v sqlStr "INSERT INTO MyTable (id, line) VALUES (NULL, '%s')" "$line"
echo "$sqlStr"
```

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (`id`, `line`) VALUES (NULL, 'This is a "line from a file" with words')
```

Comment: How would the printf line change if there were multiple variables being inputted?

Comment: This still causes error in mysql call. It echos fine, as it did before. The actual sql command that parses the quotes throws an SQL syntax error. I attempted this method with `, ' and " around the %s.

Comment: Perhaps `printf -v sqlStr "INSERT INTO MyTable (id, line) VALUES (NULL, '%s')" "$line"`

Comment: That worked! Thanks Walter A! When the answer is edited to match the solution I will mark it as correct!